# imaps builder map not viewed in php localhost properly

Tags: php, javascript, html

I designed a map using `imapsbuilder`. it gave me a javascript which can be used inside my code to view the map but the problem is its not being viewed properly in php. Someone please help me.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://g3.imapbuilder.net/_api/?s=66e09d9be7bef2be0a12285bac364c88&m=22671" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://g3.imapbuilder.net/_api/?s=d0b187c9f3cae7f52b14798f2ac89be0&m=22674" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into a php file outside the  tag and seems it works fine.
So you can try to close your php tag, put the script code and then open the php tag again.